# How can I run these two command in one VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

If the taskbar in hide mode then show it and reverse.

```vb
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "nircmd.exe win show class Shell_TrayWnd"
Set oShell = Nothing'
```

```vb
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "nircmd.exe win hide class Shell_TrayWnd"
Set oShell = Nothing'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called "toggling" and you need only one action for it. From the [`nircmd` documentation](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/win.html):

> **togglehide:** Toggles the specified windows between visible and hidden state.

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "nircmd.exe win togglehide class Shell_TrayWnd"
```